# Thread.sleep () in while loop with RequestQue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep, request-queueing

what i'm trying to do is while loop with delay of 15 seconds and inside the loop i want to execute volley request .. the loop is working but with no delay

this is my code : (client2 is the volley request method )

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {@Override
    public void run() {
        while (h < taxiidlist.size() && assined == false && requested == true) {
            handler2.post(new Runnable() {@Override
                public void run() {

                    client2(user.id, taxiidlist.get(h));

                    h++;
                }

            });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: What is not working or working incorrectly?

Comment: the while loop is working but with no delay of 15 seconds

Comment: Is it a typo? Your bracing looks off, close brace missing. The try/Thread.sleep block appears inside your new Runnable declaration. But I'm surprised if that's actually the case if that would compile.

Comment: Just what I was about to say. The try-catch code should be inside the `run()` method to be executed when your `client2()` is being executed. Wonder how it is working.

Comment: yes it is a typo , i will edit the post .

Comment: try/catch is inside run() method , i will edit the post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why the code isn't working. One possible issue might be that you have forgotten to invoke `run()` within the `handler.post()` where your inner Runnable instance is being passed.

Try with this sample code (loop executed just once) and see if you can spot the issue in yours.

```
private static List<String> taxiidlist = new ArrayList<>();
static int h = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int id = 0;
    boolean assined = false;
    boolean requested = true;
    taxiidlist.add("One");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (h <= taxiidlist.size() && assined == false && requested == true) {
                post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        client2(id, taxiidlist.get(h));
                        h++;

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1500);
                            System.out.println("slept!");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                break;
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

static void post(Runnable runnable) {
    System.out.println("post!");
    runnable.run();

}

static void client2(int id, String s) {
    System.out.println("client2!");
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you , i don't know why but your code is working

Comment: The only change I made was to add code to invoke the inner Runnable with the `run()` method. I have kept everything else as close as I could with yours so that it makes it easier for you to track down the issue. Is your `client2()` being called?